# Problems installing hydro from source

Tags: ros, husky, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I can successfully install the catkin (wet?) packages using the install from source on Ubuntu instructions found on the ROS website.  However, I seem to still be missing packages that are installed when I install from binary.  Looking at the Wiki for installing from source, it mentions "To utilize the things installed there simply source that file. Lets do that now before building the rest of ROS:".  However, it never mentions how to build the rest of ROS.

So I figured, let's look at the source install documentation from Groovy.  It is very similar, but has how to build the ROS (dry) packages.  However, when I try to follow those instructions, substituting hydro for groovy, it tells me that there are no dry packages for Hydro.

I still don't understand why these files are not there when I compile from source, unless possibly they aren't actually part of ROS.  They (apt-get packages) get installed as part of the dependency process when installing the HRATC2014 framework.  See below:

```
dime@hratc4:~$ dpkg -S /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libhusky_gazebo_plugins.so /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcontroller_manager.so 
ros-hydro-husky-gazebo-plugins: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libhusky_gazebo_plugins.so
ros-hydro-controller-manager: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcontroller_manager.so
```

These don't get installed as part of the source install, so do I need to look elsewhere for their source?

Edit:
You are correct, and this is the web page we are following. The problem is, currently robot_pose_ekf does not integrate GPS data.  However, clearpath robotics has code (navigation stack) with a modified robot_pose_ekf that does integrate GPS data.   Please Google "clearpath robotics robot_pose_ekf" (I can't post links yet due to karma).  At the bottom it says "where to get the code", and you can see the github directory where we're getting the modified navigation stack.  Note, that this is the entire navigation stack, not just robot_pose_ekf.  Being new to the ROS ecosystem, we just assumed we could replace the navigation directory in the ROS source, build (which we did succesfully) and run it.  However, we still need extra packages provided by the HRATC2014 competition, and weren't able to integrate them with our compiled version -- this is where we are hung up...the ROS desktop-full is installed (along with needed .so files from HRATC2014) in /opt/ros.  My custom build of ROS with modified navigation stack is in home_dir/catkin_workspace1/install_isolated.  Should I be doing the navigation source build in an "overlay" workspace?  And by all means, if I'm simply asking something that's documented, just point me in the right direction, because I haven't been able to find it.  Thanks for all your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147826/problems-installing-hydro-from-source/) by [dime](https://answers.ros.org/users/14236/dime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be some misconception about what is "ROS". When you installed ROS, probaly you chose the `desktop_full` variant. This gives you maybe around 250 packages. However there are over 1000 packages released for ROS hydro. Just because they don't get installed with any of the core variants (base, robot, desktop, desktop_full, etc) does not mean they are not "part of ROS".

As you noticed, these additional ROS packages seem to be not part of packages needed for the "HRATC2014 framework" (I don't know what that is). You can of course install also those from source. `rosinstall_generator` is your friend here.

I guess the question is really, what you are trying to acheive. Usually it does not make sense to install everything from source on Ubuntu. It is much more economical to install almost everything with apt-get, and then create an overlay workspace with just the packages you want to modify and thus compile from source (including any packages you need that depend on the ones you modify). Again, `rosdep`, `rosinstall_generator` and `wstool` are your friend for this.

**Edit:** In response to your comment.

It is probably best to install the core ROS system from APT, and then checkout only the ones you need to customize from source in an overlay. In catkin, you should not manually modify the environment variables like ROS_PACKAGE_PATH / LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but rather make sure you have sourced your underaly (the core install in /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash) before invoking `catkin_make` on your overlay with the source packages for the first time. Even if you want to build everything from source, I would still advice to install the core pacakges in an underlay workspace, then create a second overlay workspace for development. Else configuratoin/compilation will be slow and you cannot use catkin_make due to some non-catkin packages.

You should follow the tutorial at [http://www2.isr.uc.pt/~embedded/events/HRATC2014/Simulator.html](http://www2.isr.uc.pt/%7Eembedded/events/HRATC2014/Simulator.html). Which packages on top of the three in the `hratc2014_framework.rosinstall` do you want to install from source exactly?

**Edit 2:**

In response to your update, you have multiple possibilities. I am assuming that you want the hratc 2014 on top of a ROS install where only the navigation stack is replaced.

**Option 1**

The first option is to create a workspace with the hratc packages and the modified navigation stack.

```
# set up workspace with hratc and custom navigation
mkdir ~/hratc2014_workspace
cd ~/hratc2014_workspace
wstool init src https://raw.github.com/ras-sight/hratc2014_framework/master/hratc2014_framework.rosinstall -j8
wstool set navigation https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/navigation.git --git -v hydro-devel -t src
wstool update -t src
# install dependencies from debian
rosdep install --from-path src -i --rosdistro hydro
# source the underlay and compile the workspace
. /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
catkin_make
```

This is the most convenient option, but there are some subtle pitfalls with this. For example, anything you install from debians that depends on the navigation stack was compiled with the released packages, but you now have "shadowed" those with your custom ones. If the ABI is different, you might run into trouble. However this case might not arise for you.

**Option 2**

The other way is to create a custom ros install from source (dektop_full or whatever) where you replace the navigation stack with the version of clearpath. This is cleaner, because now you are not "shadowing" one version of the navigation stack with a custom one. You use this workspace as the underlay for your workspace with the hratc2014 packages. In order to add additional packages to the underlay (to fulfil all dependencies of the hratc2014 packages), you can include additional packages in the underlay with `wstool` and `rosinstall_generator`.

Initialize the underlay with the desktop_full metapackage and our custom navigation

```
 mkdir ~/ros_ws
 cd ~/ros_ws
 wstool init src
 wstool set navigation https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/navigation.git --git -v hydro-devel -t src
 wstool update -t src -j8
```

Get a .rosinstall file for all dependencies of the navigation stack and all of ros in the desktop_full variant. CAVEAT: This only works if the clearpath for of the navigation stack has the same dependencies as the released version.

```
 rosinstall_generator navigation desktop_full --deps --rosdistro hydro --deps-only --tar > deps.rosinstall
```

Merge the deps into the workspace, fetch all sources and build everything.

```
wstool merge deps.rosinstall -t src
wstool update -t src -j8
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Prepare the overlay workspace with the hratc sources.

```
mkdir ~/hratc2014_ws
cd ~/hratc2014_ws
wstool init src https://raw.github.com/ras-sight/hratc2014_framework/master/hratc2014_framework.rosinstall -j8
```

We cannot use rosdep to find missing dependencies, and rosinstall_generator does not have support for the same kind of --from-paths option (see https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosinstall_generator/issues/25), so a little bit of manual work is needed.

First source the underlay, then let rosdep tell us what is not there already.

```
source ~/ros_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
rosdep rosdep check --from-paths src -i
```

For this gives the following output (on os x):

```
System dependencies have not been satisified:
homebrew    ros-hydro-husky-navigation
homebrew    ros-hydro-ros-control
homebrew    ros-hydro-husky-gazebo-plugins
homebrew    ros-hydro-ros-controllers
homebrew    ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control
homebrew    ros-hydro-hector-gazebo-plugins
homebrew    ros-hydro-gazebo-plugins
homebrew    ros-hydro-gazebo-ros
```

From that output you can deduce the following command to get a .rosinstall file for all missing dependecies. Take care to change `-` in the package name to `_`.

```
rosinstall_generator husky_navigation ros_control husky_gazebo_plugins ros_controllers gazebo_ros_control hector_gazebo_plugins gazebo_plugins gazebo_ros --deps --rosdistro hydro --tar --exclude RPP > hratc-deps.rosinstall
```

Now do back to the underlay and add the additional packages.

```
cd ~/ros_ws
wstool merge ~/hratc2014_ws/hratc-deps.rosinstall -t src
wstool update -t src -j8
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Finally we are ready to build the overlay

```
cd ~/hratc2014_ws
catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dime](https://answers.ros.org/users/14236/dime/) on 2014-04-03**:
I pulled the source for ROS because we needed to include a third-party modification to parts of the navigation stack (and it was only available in source).  Then, I need to also use some dependencies that get installed when I use rosdep on the catkin workspace provided by the competition (HRATC2014).  However, rosdep installs these in /opt/ros/hydro.  My catkin install complained about being mixed type packages so we have to use catkin_make_isolated, which installed it into my home directory.  I haven't been able to figure out how to make my local, source compiled ROS know where the other libraries are.  I tried ROS_PACKAGE_PATH / LD_LIBRARY_PATH, etc., but there's some concept I'm missing here.  It still doesn't seem to integrate well (i.e. controller_manager/spawn -- one of the dependencies, is never found).  I'd have though there'd just be an environment variable that we could set equal to /opt/ros/hydro or /opt/ros/hydro/lib and it would just pick up the other libraries.